# Get Folder Address In DLL

Tags: wpf, dll

According This Images:

[image]

I have a folder named Gallery in Main.data Project.
I added Main.Data.Dll as reference in main project.
I want to show this images in mainwindow form.I change images build action to resource.
I want to know how can i get this folder address in main project?

in mainwindow:

```
 private void LoadImages()
        {
            foreach (var imgaddress in Directory.GetFiles((Here), "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                //Do Some...
            }
        }
```

What Do i must write(Here)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant solution, but something like this would get you the resource strings or URIs for all the jpgs in Main.Data:

```
private void LoadImages ()
{
    var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("Main.Data.dll");
    var rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(asm.GetName().Name + ".g", asm);
    var resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, true, true);
    var resourceUris = new List<Uri>();
    var resourceStrings = new List<String>();
    foreach (var resource in
        resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().Where(resource => ((string) resource.Key).EndsWith("jpg")))
    {
        resourceStrings.Add((string)resource.Key);
        resourceUris.Add(
            new Uri(String.Format("pack://application:,,,/Main.Data;component/{0}",
                                    ((string) resource.Key))));
    }

    rm.ReleaseAllResources();

    // Do something with resourceStrings or resourceUris...

}
```