# How to read a text file stored in an external DLL resource in c#

Tags: dll, resources, external

I am trying to read a text file (.xml) which is stored on a external DLL.
I can get the files stored in the DLL by this way: [Get Folder Address In DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319576/get-folder-address-in-dll).

But I have a problem when I want to read the text file using:

```
File.OpenRead(Uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

The Uri is like:

```
pack://application:,,,/Library;component/catalog.xml
```

There are more elements on my DLL like images. When I try to load them, it work well.

```
BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Library;component/image.png"));
```

The image is well displayed.

Why it does not work with my text file?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem by using a StreamResourceInfo like this:

```
System.Windows.Resources.StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream("pack://application:,,,/Library;component/catalog.xml");
```

Thanks to this post: [Opening a file from a pack URI in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532381/opening-a-file-from-a-pack-uri-in-wpf)